# Setting Width of <div> with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `<table>` which is dynamically created so the width is unknown.  I'm trying to add horizontal scroll bars to the top and bottom of it.  My current code...

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="div1" width="<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write(mytext);</script>">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
   <div class="div2">
      <table id="table_width">
         *table content goes here*
      </table>
   </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper2")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
});
$(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper1")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
});
});

var mytext = document.getElementById("table_width").offsetWidth; //Method 1
var mytext = document.getElementById("table_width").style.width = width + 'px'; //Method 2
</script>
```

In the last few lines, I've tried two different methods to set the width of the containing `<div>` to be `mytext`.

Any ideas why either method isn't working?  BTW, I'm not trying both methods at the same time the way it's shown here.

Comment: You have no element with ID `table_width`

Comment: I'm not seeing an element in your HTML named `table_width`.

Comment: Forgot to add that in... sorry.  It's there now though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be this.

The script you have written to find mytext is being executed after the table is created. But by the time the div is created value of mytext is not known. So I would recommend doing this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<div class="wrapper1">
   <div id="div1">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
 <div class="div2">
   <table>
     *table content goes here*
   </table>
 </div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       $(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
          $(".wrapper2")
      .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
   });
$(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
$(".wrapper1")
    .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
 });
});

var mytext = document.getElementById("table_width").offsetWidth; //Method 1
var mytext = document.getElementById("table_width").style.width ; //Method 2

 document.getElementById('div1').width = mytext;
 </script>


</html>
```

The above code changes the width of the div after finding the value of mytext.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on my end, but I see what you're trying to do.  Is there an error in your code maybe?

Comment: I ended up using part of your suggest solution and part of @Rob's.  Thus, the upvote for your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To find the width of an element you need to use `window.getComputedStyle` followed by `getPropertyValue` on that returned value. What you are doing now only gives you the CSS value which is not set.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: I ended up using part of your suggest solution and part of @Avinash Kadimisetty's.  Thus, the upvote for your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using parts of both of the suggested answers for this question.  After a lot of fiddling, I ended up with this for the final Javascript...

```
var elem = document.getElementById("table_width");
var mytext = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("width");
$('#div1').css({'width':mytext});
$('#div1').css({'overflow': 'scroll'});
```